# Wordpress old/updated/deleted CSS files are being served minified and I cant delete them. Why?

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce, minify, w3-total-cache

### Backstory

We are using a LAMP stack (bitnami) to run a multisite Wordpress instance. This is the second time I have ran into a file that will not update when we push an update (We use git and pull the latest changes to the bitnami server).

We have noticed that when deleting (renaming for that matter) the file, it can still be retrieved by performing a GET on the resource (or the url in a browser). Also, if we were trying to make changes the changes do not come with the file - it is still the old file. Interestingly enough, the file is minified, which because of issues with this in the past we do not use any plugins that minify our CSS. So there should be no reason for it to be minified.

We have WP Total Cache - clearing all caches is successful but does not stop this from happening. (We used to use WP Super Cache, when this bug happened we decided to change plugins to WP Total Cache and purged the cache and it fixed the problem - but it is back and that no longer works).

I have also seen the trick where we can use a "?ver=###" query param on the url. This works but this would prevent us from using CloudFront for our files (currently disabled for all this testing so its not the problem either). Also I am not convinced it is a long term solution - or a solution at all since these minified files are being created and shouldnt be in the first place.

### Additional information

It may not be helpful, but the files we have noticed this with are in a theme folder that is not technically an active theme. We just use the folder for additional resources that we have created ourselves. We reference them in the head of some pages.
Example:

```
/wp-content/themes/active-theme <- The active theme
/wp-content/themes/resources <- Our custom resources
```

### Questions:

**Where is this file being stored?**

**How can I delete it?**

**How can I prevent this from wasting our time ever again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was with the bitnami server itself. The Apache2 module PageSpeed was causing the served files to be minified and cached resulting in the pages never updating no matter what we did on wordpress.

Apache:
To disable PageSpeed, comment out the following lines in your httpd.conf (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`)

```
#Include conf/pagespeed.conf
#Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

Solution found [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/oci/infrastructure/lamp/administration/disable-cache/)